# How do I run a command(with its output being piped to a file) in the background?

Tags: unix, background, command

Say I have a program `foo`, which prints a gazillion lines to the console.
How do I run it in the background, while piping its output to a file?

I tried this

```
./foo | output.txt&
```

Doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `nohup` utility, it allows to detach a command from the tty:

```
nohup sh -c "./foo 2>&1 > output.txt" &
```

Piping the output of a command to a file actually does not work, you can only redirect it: that is the `> output.txt`. Piping makes sense if what follows is a command again which accepts input from its standard input, but not for a passive file. The additional `2>&1` redirects the commands standard error output into the standard output, so that you have only one single output pipe, otherwise potential errors would still spill out to the controlling tty. The actual command here is a shell invoked, that is because piping will break the sequence otherwise.